# How to upper case a regular expressions pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently looking at a project which highly utilises Regular Expressions.  The input strings are already upper cased and so the regex IgnoreCase flag has been set.  The internal MS RegEx engine though is then changing all the case back to lower which is an unnecessary hit.  Changing the reg expresions pattern to upper case and removing the flag helps the performance.

Does anyone know of a library of algorithm which can upper case the Reg ex patterns without affecting the group names or escaped chars?

Comment: `ToUpper()` on your pattern string. This shouldn't affect the special chars.

Comment: I'm afraid it can, for example \w or \s has quite different meaning when ToUpper()-ed

Comment: It certainly will affect special chars: `\s` and `\S` are not the same. You probably have to parse the regex yourself. It's a pity that so many languages don't expose regular expressions structurally, but only serialized into strings or as opaque objects.

Comment: ++ to the above comments and: do you have tests for what your RegExes are supposed to match/not match?  If not, you risk introducing regressions no matter what RegEx-conversion approach you take.

Comment: I already have a benchmarked set of results based on a large no(1000s) of inputs.  I'm able to compare these against any results obtained by changing the regexs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go and search for lowercase letters that are not preceded by an uneven number of backslashes:

```
(?<!(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\)\p{Ll}+
```

Then pass the match to a `MatchEvaluator`, uppercase it and replace the text in the original string. I don't know C#, so this might not work right away (code snippet taken and modified a bit from [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com)), but it's a start:

```
string resultString = null;
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"(?<!                 # Negative lookbehind:
       (?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\  # Is there no odd number of backslashes
      |                    # nor
       \(\?<?\p{L}*        # (?<tags or (?modifiers
      )                    # before the current position?
      \p{Ll}+              # Then match one or more letters", 
    new MatchEvaluator(ComputeReplacement), RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

public String ComputeReplacement(Match m) {
    // You can vary the replacement text for each match on-the-fly
    return @"\0".ToUpper();  // or whatever is needed for uppercasing in .NET
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!        # assert that the string before the current position doesn't match:
 (?<!\\)    # assert that we start at the first backslash in the series
 (?:\\\\)*  # match an even number of backslashes
 \\         # match one backslash
)
\p{Ll}+     # now match any sequence of lowercase letters
```

Comment: One more thing: This regex will alter in-place modifiers like `(?s)`, and I suspect that `(?S)` is not going to work correctly. So if you have those in your regexes, this approach might need to be altered. It will also produce undesired results with Unicode properties like `\p{Ll}`...

Comment: Will this not upper case any group names as well? I have a constraint that any existing group names in <tags> have to still remain in the same case as already set.

Comment: Yes, it will. It should be possible to account for that, though. Wait a second; I'll edit my answer.